# Typescript and SystemJS can not import a class

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I am a new in Typescript and SystemJS and
I started from this simple example, expecting that my ts files will be transpilled on the fly.
I created an index.html file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
        <script>
          SystemJS.config({ 
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            map: {
              'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js'
            },
            packages: {
              src: {
                defaultExtension: 'ts'
              }
            } 
          })
          SystemJS.import('src/main').then(function(m){
             console.log(m);
          }, function(error){
             console.log(error);
          });
        </script>
     </head>

     <body>

     </body>
</html>
```

Then put this two files into src folder.

```
//main.ts

import {Person} from './person';
let person = new Person();
console.log(person.name);


//person.ts

export class Person {
    public name: string = 'David';
}
```

And now I don't see anything in my console, no errors no outputs.
I've figured out that the problem lays in this line.

```
import {Person} from './person';
```

Because if I comment it I will see this reasonable error.

> Error: Invalid or unexpected token

Help me please where should I pay my attention to?

Comment: Your TS code looks fine, I tested it in a project I was working on and it works like expected. I don't use SystemJS, maybe the problem lies there?

Comment: Yes, and what wonder me that I can not catch an exception in .then() construction, it simply does not get inside and dies somewhere silently.

Answer (score 0):

Did not you miss the script tag to typescript?

```
<script src="node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>
```

I believe [this](http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/) is the source you have used as sample. They explicitly mention this kind of error.

Comment: Yes I used this example and got 
 http://localhost:8001/typescript 404 not found.  
Then I added map property to direct it.
Never the less after adding explicit tag this sctipt loads just twice and it does not help :-(.

Comment: Make sure you have installed typescript locally and its folder can be reached by http server using path "node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js". Just try to navigate to localhost:8001/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js. It should be accessible

Comment: Three of them are downloaded by the web page system.js, typescript.js, and main.ts but person.ts not.

Comment: Maybe I need to add tsconfig.json and put something in it?

Comment: You can try. It looks like tsc does not actually transpiles the ts files and they are executed as is.

Comment: Check this example also: http://lishman.io/angular-2-configuration. Do not mind its for angular. Basics are the same. The configuration there is a bit different

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the link. 
I added and configured a plugin-typescript in this way and it started to work fine.

```
      SystemJS.config({ 
        transpiler: 'ts',
        map: {
          'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib',
          'ts': 'node_modules/plugin-typescript/lib/plugin.js'
        },
      packages: {
        "typescript": {
          "main": "typescript.js",
          "meta": {
            "typescript.js": {
              "exports": "ts"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      })
```